# Inner tube lengh

Tags: innertube

I have a load of inner tubes that are bigger than the wheel and tyre in lengh, I had a puncture in the part of the inner tube that was folded inside the tyre, will this puncture again ? Is it important that the inner tube and tyre sizes match ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes - the inner tube width and length should match the tyre in which they are installed, within the posted width range.

A mismatch works as a temporary get-you-home bodge but is not recommended for long term solution due to accelerated wear on the corners and folds, and a tube that is folded tends to make the outer rolling surface non-round.

Take a moment to read through the "related" questions on the right-hand side of this web page.  Many of them are relevant, like [Should inner tube have excess length?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/4434/should-inner-tube-have-excess-length)

Yes it will puncture again.